# WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager Problems Addind a new Identity Provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have installed an instance of WSO2 API Manager 1.8.0 and WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 in two different machines. I have configured the Identity Server as the Key Manager following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+the+Key+Manager) instructions. After several failure tries, it looks as working properly.
When I try to adding a new Identity Provider, it fails whith the following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 199 in the jsp file: /idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
SCOPE cannot be resolved or is not a field

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 199 in the jsp file: /idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
REQUEST_METHOD cannot be resolved or is not a field

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 199 in the jsp file: /idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
SF_OAUTH2_TOKEN_ENDPOINT cannot be resolved or is not a field


at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:700)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603)
at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:335)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

As I have seeen the code I see that a constant Class doesn't have the following  fields.

SCOPE
REQUEST_METHOD
SF_OAUTH2_TOKEN_ENDPOINT

Anyone configured properly WSO2 IS as key manager and had this problems?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that WSO2IS 5.0.0 and APIM 1.8.0 key manager installation does not work properly.  There are some issues.  Please check the public [jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3034).